# Data to save in Yii not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

I tried to save these test data into the database if the record haven't exist yet. But when I try to create new record, it returns fail. I'm not sure what's wrong.

**This is the code to check whether the registration id exist or not:**

```
public static function getEventRegistration($registration_code)
{
    $model = EventRegistration::model()->findByAttributes(array('registration_code'=>$registration_code));
        if($model!==null)
        return $model;
}
```

**This is the code to save the new record:**

```
public function actionEventReg()
{
    $tmps = HUB::getEventRegistration('999881');
    if(empty($tmps)){
        // echo 'record does not exist';

        //create new registration
        $object = new EventRegistration;
        $object->event_code = '206218';
        $object->event_vendor_code = 'bizzabo'; 
        $object->registration_code = '0123456';
        $object->full_name = 'test rifff';
        $object->first_name = 'test';
        $object->last_name = 'rifff';
        $object->email = 'rifhan@mymagic.my';
        $object->phone = '';
        $object->organization = '';
        $object->gender = '';
        $object->age_group = '';
        $object->where_found = '';
        $object->persona = '';
        $object->paid_fee = '';
        $object->is_attended = '';
        $object->date_registered = '';
        $object->date_payment = '';
        $object->json_original = '';
        $object->date_added = time();
        $object->date_modified = time();

        if($object->save()){
            $success = 'success';
        }else{
            $fail = 'fail';
        }
        //create junk
        $junk = new Junk;
        $junk->code = 'test-getRegistrationNotExist-'.time();
        $junk->content = sprintf('successfully insert data: %s or (%s). With first name is %s and last name is %s', $success, $fail, $object->first_name, $object->last_name);
        $junk->save();
    }else{
        // echo 'record exist';

        //create junk
        $junk = new Junk;
        $junk->code = 'test-getRegistrationExist-'.time();
        $junk->content = sprintf('called on: %s with first name is %s and last name is %s', Yii::app()->params['masterDomain'], $tmps->first_name, $tmps->last_name);
        $junk->save();
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I change the code like Yupik adviced to dump the error like below :

```
public function actionBizzaboCallback()
{
    $junk = new Junk;
    $junk->code = 'bizzabo-bizzaboCallback-'.time();

    $junk->content .= serialize($_POST);

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        // fetch RAW input
        $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

        // decode json
        $objects = json_decode($json);

        // expecting valid json
        if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            die(header('HTTP/1.0 415 Unsupported Media Type'));
        } else {
            // check if registration exist
            $tmps = HUB::getEventRegistrationByID($objects->details->items[0]->ticketId);

                if(empty($tmps)){
                    //1. echo 'record does not exist';

                    //2. create new registration
                    $object = new EventRegistration;
                    $object->event_code = $objects->eventId;
                    $object->event_vendor_code = 'bizzabo'; 
                    $object->registration_code = $objects->details->items[0]->ticketId;

                    $object->full_name = sprintf('%s %s', $objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->firstName, $objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->lastName);

                    $object->first_name = $objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->firstName;
                    $object->last_name = $objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->lastName;
                    $object->email = $objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->email;

                    $object->phone = 'null';
                    // $object->phone = $objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->mobileNumber;
                    $object->organization = 'null';
                    //$object->organization = $objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->organisation__instit;

                    $object->gender = 'unknown';
                     if(isset($objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->gender))
                     {
                        if(stristr($objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->gender, 'female'))
                        {
                            $gender = 'female';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(stristr($objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->gender, 'male'))
                            {
                                $gender = 'male';
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $object->age_group = $objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->age_group;

                    $object->where_found = $objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->how_did_you_hear_abo;

                    $object->persona = $objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->type_of_person;

                    $object->paid_fee = $objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->ticketPaid;

                    $object->date_registered = $objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->created;

                    $object->date_payment = $objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->created;

                    $object->json_original = $json;

                    $object->date_added = time();
                    $object->date_modified = time();

                    if($object->save()){
                        $success = 'success';
                    }else{
                        var_dump($object->getErrors());
                        $fail = 'fail';
                    }

                    //3. create junk
                    $junk = new Junk;
                    $junk->code = 'bizzabo-getBizzaboRegistrationIntoDB-'.time();
                    $junk->content = sprintf('ticket id: %s does not exist. %s into database.', $objects->details->items[0]->ticketId, $fail);

                }else{
                    //1. echo 'record exist';

                    //2. create junk
                    $junk = new Junk;
                    $junk->code = 'bizzabo-getBizzaboRegistrationExisted-'.time();
                    $junk->content = sprintf('ticket id: %s does exist. Did not update into database.',$objects->details->items[0]->ticketId);
                }
            $junk->content .= sprintf('Get error : %s ', $object->getErrors());               
        }
    }
    $junk->save();
}
```

[But when I try to print *$object->getErrors()* in junk file, it displayed *Array*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1MJK.png)

Comment: you can try this `$object->save(false)` but this will skip your server side validation

Answer (score 0):

**Code fix**

This method:

```
public static function getEventRegistration($registration_code)
{
    $model = EventRegistration::model()->findByAttributes(array('registration_code'=>$registration_code));
        if($model!==null)
        return $model;
}
```

You're checking if `$model` is not null, if that's true, you're returning `$model`, otherwise nothing, so it's like you're returning null. Change this to:

```
public static function getEventRegistration($registration_code)
{
    return EventRegistration::model()->findByAttributes(array('registration_code'=>$registration_code));
}
```

---

**Main problem:**

To check what's wrong in your new object, simply put `var_dump($object->getErrors());die;` in else statement:

```
    if($object->save()){
        $success = 'success';
    }else{
        var_dump($object->getErrors());die;
        $fail = 'fail';
    }
```

Then try to save it - if it fails one more time - you will see what's exacly wrong with your validation.

Comment: how if i want to save POST data in the object?

Comment: You can save it as string, but you need to use `json_encode()` on the data before.

Comment: Hi @Yupik , I tried to do like you advised, but it returns the error as : Array. Please refer to the edited version in the question above. Thank you!

Comment: You're saving `$junk` even if `$object->save()` succeed. Use `die;` after `var_dump` to get exacly what's wrong.

Comment: so should I replace `$junk->save()` to `die;`? But where I'm going to see the error since this function will be triggered when there's new registration coming from the server side?

Comment: No, i've pasted you how it should looks like in answer. Trigger it manually and you will see the result on your browser.

Comment: I've added `die;` and commit the file to staging. Called the webhook and my junk file is not created because it didn't save if it failed to save the object data. Now, how should I see the error message? However, I realised if I input the data manually, it saved successfully. But if I want to save the JSON POST data, it returns fail.

Comment: If you're dying script right after `var_dump()`, you should see what's wrong exacly when you call this webhook. Your script should stop here and display what's under `$model->getErrors()`. Go through your script step by step, even dying it line by line and try to debug it.

Comment: Successfully saved the data into db! Thank you! I actually removed this condition check `$tmps = HUB::getEventRegistrationByID($objects->details->items[0]->ticketId);` because it will always return true.

Answer (score 0):

try check validation properly

```
......
}else{

    $junk = new Junk;
    $junk->code = 'test-getRegistrationExist-'.time();
    $junk->content = sprintf('called on: %s with first name is %s and last name is %s', Yii::app()->params['masterDomain'], $tmps->first_name, $tmps->last_name);
     if ($junk->validate()) {
         $junk->save();
    } else {
        // validation failed: $errors is an array containing error messages
        var_dump( $junk->errors);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

are u trying to save `$object`? if yes, wheres the syntax `$object->save()`?

```
public function actionEventReg()
{
    ....
        $object->date_added = time();
        $object->date_modified = time();
        **$object->save();**

        if($object->save()){
            $success = 'success';
        }else{
            $fail = 'fail';
        }
       ...
    }
}
```

try to put that `$object->save();`

Comment: `if($object->save()){` here? You've just pasted it here.